# Backspace character gets added in FIFO

Tags: c, unix, ipc, fifo

I am learning about FIFOs and have written an iterative server that takes requests from multiple clients. The clients request for a file by writing to the server's well known fifo. The server reads from it's FIFO and puts the contents of the requested file in the a new FIFO which the client reads from. I run the server. When I run the client for the first time, things work as expected and the client reads the contents of the file. When I run the client for the 2nd time, the message from the client gets prefixed with a backspace character. I have no idea where this backspace is coming from. Any ideas?
This is the server code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<errno.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include"fifo.h"

#define SERVFIFO "/tmp/fifo.serv"
#define FILE_MODE (S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH)

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int readfifo, dummywrite, filefd, writefd, n;
    int clientpid;
    char buff[MAXLINE], *spaceptr, fifoname[MAXLINE];

    if (mkfifo(SERVFIFO, FILE_MODE) < 0 && errno != EEXIST) {
        printf("Can't create %s", SERVFIFO);
    }

    readfifo = open(SERVFIFO, O_RDONLY, 0);
    dummywrite = open(SERVFIFO, O_WRONLY, 0);

    while ((n = Readline(readfifo, buff, MAXLINE)) > 0) {
        printf("Read data from the fifo:%s and the length is:%d and the character is:%d\n", buff, strlen(buff), buff[0]);

        if (buff[n - 1] == '\n') {
            n--;
            printf("I am also omitting the newline\n");
        }

        buff[n] = '\0';
        printf("Buff just after read is:%s and length is %d", buff, strlen(buff));

        if ((spaceptr = strchr(buff, ' ')) == NULL) {
            printf("Bad request from client");
            continue;
        }

        printf("Found the space:%c\n", *(spaceptr + 1));
        *spaceptr++ = '\0';
        printf("The value of buffer now is:%s and the length of buffer is:%d and the culprit is %d\n", buff, strlen(buff), *(buff + 0));
        clientpid = atol(buff);
        printf("The client pid is %ld\n", clientpid);
        snprintf(fifoname, sizeof(fifoname), "/tmp/fifoname.%ld", clientpid);

        if (mkfifo(fifoname, FILE_MODE) < 0 && errno != EEXIST) {
            perror("Can't create the fifo");
            continue;
        }

        printf("Successfully created fifo %s for client\n", fifoname);

        if ((writefd = open(fifoname, O_WRONLY, 0)) < 0) {
            printf("Cannot open %s", fifoname);
            continue;
        }

        if ((filefd = open(spaceptr, O_RDONLY, 0)) < 0) {
            printf("Error opening file\n");
            continue;
        }
        else {
            while ((n = read(filefd, buff, MAXLINE))) {
                write(writefd, buff, n);
            }

            close(filefd);
            close(writefd);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the client code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<errno.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#define SERVER_FIFO "/tmp/fifo.serv"
#define MAXLINE 100
#define MSG "%ld sup.c"
#define READFIFO "/tmp/fifoname.%ld"
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int writefifo, readfifo, n;
    char buff[MAXLINE];
    pid_t self_pid = getpid();
    printf("Started client with PID:%ld\n", self_pid);
    writefifo = open(SERVER_FIFO, O_WRONLY, 0);
    snprintf(buff, sizeof(buff), MSG, self_pid);
    printf("The message to be written to the server is:%s and the length of the message is %d\n", buff, strlen(buff));

    if ((n = write(writefifo, buff, sizeof(buff))) != sizeof(buff)) {
        perror("Unable to write to server fifo");
        exit(0);
    }

    printf("Message written to the server; Waiting to read contents\n");
    snprintf(buff, sizeof(buff), READFIFO, self_pid);
    readfifo = open(buff, O_RDONLY, 0);

    while ((n = read(readfifo, buff, MAXLINE))) {
        write(STDOUT_FILENO, buff, n);
    }

    close(readfifo);
    close(writefifo);
    unlink(buff);
}
```

Comment: Spaces are a beautiful thing...

Comment: Thanks for the edit but any clues regarding the problem?

Comment: Could there be leftovers in the FIFO from a previous run? I see that when the FIFO already exists, you just continue instead of deleting and recreating.

Comment: The client writes 100 bytes to the server, even though it only initialized the first ten or so bytes.  The chances are the the backspace you got is a coincidence caused by lack of data initialization.  The client should probably create its own FIFO and tell the server what the name of the FIFO is.  The server has a well-known FIFO name so that any process can talk to it.  The message from the client to the server should include the information needed to open the FIFO that the client has created.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is a chopped up version of your real program because this doesn't display the behavior you describe.  A couple of things:

(1) In the server

```
readfifo = open(SERVFIFO, O_RDONLY, 0);
dummywrite = open(SERVFIFO, O_WRONLY, 0);
```

I assume you knew that if you open the well-known fifo without something on the other end the open will block.  This still blocks on the O_RONLY open because in normal circumstances you will run the server before any clients.  If you want to avoid blocking just open it once as read/write.

(2) In the client

```
snprintf(buff, sizeof(buff), READFIFO, self_pid);
readfifo = open(buff, O_RDONLY, 0);
```

This is not doing what you think.  Your client writes a message to the server's fifo and *the server* creates the client's fifo with `mkfifo`.  Since the client runs first that fifo is not going to exist when you do this `open`.  You are, in effect, trying to open a plain file (that doesn't exist) as READ ONLY.  You can't read a file that doesn't exist so this `open` fails but since you don't check the open status you don't know it.

(3) unlink your FIFOs when you are done with them.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Duck. Regarding point 1, I introduced the dummywrite because if the FIFO is not open for write, then the read will return a 0 in the server's while loop and I will have to close the FIFO and call open again.

Comment: What makes you think that?  The read will block until there is something to read.

Comment: Regarding point 2, it actually works because when I do the open, it blocks until the server opens the FIFO for writing. So the open here does not fail, it blocks. The whole thing works fine on the 1st client request. On subsequent requests, because of the "backspace" character being prefixed to the client request, the atol(clientpid) fails and returns "0".

Comment: If the FIFO is not open for writing prior to a read call to an empty FIFO, the read returns 0. If there is a prior descriptor open for writing, it blocks. This is what I learnt in theory and I am pretty sure about that. If I did not have the dummywrite open, I checked that the while loop exits after the first client sends its request. This is an iterative server and I need it to keep blocking when there is no data in the FIFO. Correct me if I am wrong here.

Comment: The reason for opening the server fifo for writing is so that there is *always* a writer - the server itself.  This prevents the server from not getting an EOF when all clients close their end.  Because the server never sees EOF it doesn't have to close and reopen all the time.